# NopCommerce, C#, MVC, Elastic Search multiple parameters

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, elasticsearch, nopcommerce

Anyone have an idea about how to pass multiple parameters in the elastic search using c#? 
And also how to join multiple tables in the elastic search using C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var result= ConnectionToES.EsClient().Search<StoreMapping>(s => s
    .MatchAll()
     .From(0)
     .Size(100000)
     .Index("IndexName")
     .Type("typeName")
  .Query(q => q.Term(j => j.EntityName, "product") && q.Term(j => j.StoreId, StoreID)));
```